# Creating Lambda@edge function with Terraform and Serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to create a Lambda@edge function with Terraform (iam roles) and Serverless framework, the pipeline is completed but CloudFront not able to connect to the Lambda with this error message

```
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
```

I am not too familiar with the Lambda@edge setup (and Terraform), from the AWS console, I can see the Lambda's `arn` saved into CloudFront's behavior section, but cannot see any trigger in the Lambda.

This is the Terraform setup

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "sls-user-policy" {
  name = "${var.service_name}-sls-user-policy-${terraform.workspace}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:List*",
                "cloudformation:Get*",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_number}:stack/${var.service_name}*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
                "cloudfront:ListDistributionsByLambdaFunction",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_number}:role/${var.service_name}-${terraform.workspace}-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_number}:role/${var.service_name}*-lambdaRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_number}:role/aws-service-role/ops.apigateway.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAPIGateway",
                "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_number}:role/aws-service-role/replicator.lambda.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForLambdaReplicator",
                "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_number}:role/aws-service-role/logger.cloudfront.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForCloudFrontLogger"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:Put*",
                "events:Remove*",
                "events:Delete*",
                "events:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:events::${var.aws_account_number}:rule/${var.service_name}*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_number}:log-group::log-stream:*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
                "logs:DeleteLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents",
                "logs:PutLogsEvent"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_number}:log-group:/aws/*/${var.service_name}*:log-stream:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_number}:/aws/cloudfront/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
                "lambda:PublishVersion",
                "lambda:CreateAlias",
                "lambda:DeleteAlias",
                "lambda:UpdateAlias",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:RemovePermission",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:ListTags",
                "lambda:TagResource",
                "lambda:UntagResource",
                "lambda:EnableReplication*",
                "lambda:DisableReplication"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:${var.aws_account_number}:function:${var.service_name}*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET",
                "apigateway:POST",
                "apigateway:PUT",
                "apigateway:PATCH",
                "apigateway:DELETE",
                "apigateway:UpdateRestApiPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/restapis",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/restapis/*",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/apikeys",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/apikeys/*",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/usageplans",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/usageplans/*",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/tags",
                "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}::/tags/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:CreateDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
                "cloudfront:ListDistributions",
                "cloudfront:TagResource",
                "cloudfront:UntagResource",
                "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::${var.aws_account_number}:distribution/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "states:ListStateMachines",
              "states:ListActivities",
              "states:CreateStateMachine",
              "states:UpdateStateMachine",
              "states:DeleteStateMachine",
              "states:CreateActivity",
              "states:TagResource",
              "states:StartExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:states:*:${var.aws_account_number}:stateMachine:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_number}:${var.service_name}-*-${terraform.workspace}"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Serverless.yml

```
service: service-integration

frameworkVersion: '>=1.1.0 <2.0.0'

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function

custom:
  defaultStage: dev
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
  defaultBuild: 0
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack/${self:custom.stage}.config.js
    forceExclude:
      - aws-sdk
  serverless-iam-roles-per-function:
    defaultInherit: true
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - 'application/octet-stream'

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${self:custom.stage}
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  edgeFunction:
    handler: src/services/edge-function/edge-function.run
    memorySize: 2048
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: origin-request
          pathPattern: /api/edge-function/*/*
          isDefaultOrigin: true
          origin: https://custom-origin.com
          behavior:
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
            AllowedMethods:
              - 'GET'
              - 'HEAD'
              - 'OPTIONS'
              - 'PUT'
              - 'PATCH'
              - 'POST'
              - 'DELETE'

resources:
  Resources:
    CloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          PriceClass: PriceClass_200

    # got the below section from this link
    # https://www.pveller.com/lambda-edge-serverless/
    IamRoleLambdaExecution:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
                  - edgelambda.amazonaws.com

package:
  individually: true
```

Comment: The [max memory of an Lambda@Edge function is 128 MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-see-limits). May or may not be related.